# What will happen if we use unsupported php in hhvm?

Tags: hhvm

What will happen if we use unsupported php in hhvm. Does the code run but we don't get JIT compilation's speed improvement or we will get an error and our code will not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code will not work. The JIT isn't an addition to an existing PHP implementation. HHVM is a completely separate implementation, including differences in what will and won't run.

Comment: That said, the stuff that won't run on HHVM is a pretty small set of things nowadays, and getting smaller every day. If you run into something that doesn't work, please file an issue on GitHub.